# Adding custom number of array objects to v.findViewById(R.id.iterateHere1) without repeating code

Tags: java, android

I want to iterate 10 times adding v.findViewById(R.id.iterateHere1) without having to repeat the same syntax.

What i first had was:

```
SwitchCompat instance1 = v.findViewById(R.id.iterateHere1);
SwitchCompat instance2 = v.findViewById(R.id.iterateHere2);
SwitchCompat instance3 = v.findViewById(R.id.iterateHere3);
```

the code above was written 10 times.

I now have:

```
        SwitchCompat[] array = new SwitchCompat[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            SwitchCompat instance;
            array[i] = instance = v.findViewById(R.id.iterateHere1);
            instances.add(instance);
        }
```

which works for each instance.

My question is how do I add 10 `R.id.iterateHere1` without repeating code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain identifier of each SwitchCompat by this way :

```
SwitchCompat[] array = new SwitchCompat[10];

 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
      {
      SwitchCompat instance;
      String switchId = "iterateHere" + i;
      int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(switchId, "id", getActivity().getPackageName());

      array[i] = instance = v.findViewById(resID);
      instances.add(instance);
      }
```

Comment: Had to use `getActivity().getPackageName()` because of fragment but getting null pointer now.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe put the switches in a ViewGroup, then iterate through them, something like this

```
 ArrayList<SwitchCompat> instances = new ArrayList<>(10);
 ViewGroup parent = findViewById(R.id.parent);
        for (int index = 0; index < parent.getChildCount(); ++index) {
            View nextChild = parent.getChildAt(index);
            if (nextChild instanceof SwitchCompat) {
                instances.add((SwitchCompat) nextChild);
            }
        }
```